# java tomcat let's encrypt with docker

Tags: tomcat, docker, lets-encrypt

Can anyone provide some step by step example of setting up let's encrypt with docker tomcat image?

I have tried with `https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/` but unable to set up https .

Comment: You need a docker server running on the public internet, with a DNS entry pointing at it. Otherwise, you wont be able to catch letsencrypt’s acme challenge. May be this helps http://www.automationlogic.com/using-lets-encrypt-and-docker-for-automatic-ssl/